# Traduzir Connection String H2 (JDBC) pra MySQL (JDBC)

Tags: mysql, connectionstring

Fala pessoal,

Estou tentando fazer rodar o software OW2 Orchestra, e ele vem com uma string de conexão padrão pertencente ao H2 no seguinte formato:

```
jdbc\:h2\:file\:/tmp/orchestra-db/orchestra_core.db
```

Eu preciso traduzí-lo para uma string de MySQL (também JDBC), algo como:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
```

Com as **mesmas** informações da string original.

O problema é que eu não entendi bem o que significa a string original! Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

'jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/orchestra-db/orchestra_core.db' segue o formato:

> jdbc:h2:file:[path]

Onde:

- **jdbc:** é uma string fixa
- **h2:** é o nome do driver usado, neste caso o driver para o DB H2.
- **file:** indica ao H2 que você está usando um DB local
- **path**, neste caso '/tmp/orchestra-db/orchestra_core.db', indica o caminho do DB.

O que deve estar confundindo você são essas barras ('\') que aparecem na sua pergunta. Elas são usadas para escapar caracteres especiais, creio eu.

Basicamente tudo o que essa url diz é:

> Use um DB local que está no arquivo '/tmp/orchestra-db/orchestra_core.db'.

Se quiser  configurar uma url mysql semelhante basta apontar para o localhost, conforme o seu exemplo:

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Obs.: Você terá que escolher em qual porta o mysql irá rodar.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta! Será que não é preciso dizer ao MySQL "aonde está o DB local", como está especificado na string do H2?

Comment: @MrGuliarte Dei uma olhada na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), a princípio o Mysql não trabalha com este formato.

Comment: Entendi! Estranho, porque eu estou usando o hibernate e continuo com o erro "could not get database metadata" : / acho que vou tentar a solução inversa e trocar pro H2 rs